# Hyperlink in Repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I have a repeater with Hyperlink in Detail.aspx form .On click of hyperlink will redirect to another form (Default5.aspx).
I am trying to get the Licensename value in the Default5.aspx On click of Hyperlink inside the repeater,But the value is not getting.

Appreciate your help..Thanks

```
 <div id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="heder"
      style="border-style: none; font-weight: normal;">
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Licensename")%>  

   <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" Target="_blank" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Concat("Default5.aspx?ID=",Eval("Licensename"))%>'
                    Text="Edit"></asp:HyperLink>
  </div>
```

Comment: besides your typo in the first line (erase the `h`) what does your link look like, and what _should_ it look like?

Comment: Serv , i am not sure how to do this

Comment: Thanks,I got my answer.

Comment: feel free to completly answer for yourself, so others who might run into this problem will have a working solution

Answer (score 0):

It worked like this.Through textbox i captured the value in Default5 form.

```
<a href='<%#Eval("sampleone", "Default5.aspx?sellpostid={0}") %>' >
 <asp:Literal ID= "Literal1" runat = "server" ></asp:Literal>View Detail </a>
```